# Crear un diccionario cuyo interior tenga una lista

Tags: excel, pandas, bucles, diccionarios, matriz

Necesito crear un diccionario, en cuyo interior tenga una lista, mi diccionario tiene 5 elementos clave lo que significa que a cada elemento le corresponde una lista, para ello consideré crear un bucle for, el problema es que al visualizar mis variables, solo me aparece el último elemento clave de mi diccionario y no todos, adjunto imagen.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AieO48E0rWr2lAsz64T4PWCQx7ne)

```
matriz = pd.ExcelFile('ejemplo.xlsx')
datos = matriz.parse('Hoja1')

alcance = 36
u = np.zeros((alcance,alcance))

for i in range(0,len(datos)):
    a = datos['a'][i]
    b = datos['b'][i]
    c = datos['c'][i]
    d = datos['d'][i]
    e = datos['e'][i]
    f = datos['f'][i]
    g = datos['g'][i]
    h = datos['h'][i]
    n = datos['n'][i]

    bb = np.array([[n+h], [n+h], [n*h], [-n+h], [-n+h], [-n*h]])    

    cc = {i:bb}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que con `cc = {i:bb}` creas un nuevo diccionario **en cada iteración del ciclo** y lo reasignas a la variable `cc`. Al final tendrás un diccionario con una sola clave (última iteración del `for`) y el array generado en esa iteración como valor.

Debes crear el diccionario vacío antes de iniciar el `for` y luego agregar parejas clave-valor en cada iteración:

```
matriz = pd.ExcelFile('ejemplo.xlsx')
datos = matriz.parse('Hoja1')

cc = {}

for i in range(len(datos)):
    a = datos['a'][i]
    b = datos['b'][i]
    c = datos['c'][i]
    d = datos['d'][i]
    e = datos['e'][i]
    f = datos['f'][i]
    g = datos['g'][i]
    h = datos['h'][i]
    n = datos['n'][i]

    cc[i] = np.array([[n+h], [n+h], [n*h], [-n+h], [-n+h], [-n*h]])
```

Ten en cuenta que en la construcción del array solo usas `n` y `h`, no se si es un error o no, pero si no lo es el resto de variables sobran.

Comment: Si, bueno el resto de variables las ocuparé después, pero es justo lo que busqué con respecto a la inquietud, muchas gracias y saludos cordiales.